# How to display count results with multiple keywords anywhere in a database field

Tags: php, mysql

We have a page tcount.php where we fetch counts for BOTH keyword1 and keyword2 occuring anywhere in a text field in mysql database using php script. The counts are displayed as hyperlinks. Now after that, we want that if someone clicks on the hyperlinks, they will see the detailed results in showt.php page showing those rows of the database corresponding to only those text field containing BOTH keywords.

The url of the second page showt.php is like

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?keyword=keyword1+keyword2
```

But problem is that it shows only those results which have keyword1 and keyword2 next to each other.

For example, keyword1 is car and keyword2 is cap and our text fields are as follows -

1. car cap
2. car best cap
3. car new

Then, we want it to show 1. and 2. as results but it is showing only no. 1 in the results page.

Please help.

**Edit -**

This is the code in page 1 tcount.php -

```
$kewyWordQ = $db->query("SELECT keywords FROM Table1 ");

<?php
                while($row = $kewyWordQ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {$keyWord = $row['keywords'];
                    $keyWordsArr = explode(" ", $row['keywords']);
                    $countData = array();

                    $keyIndex = 0;
                    $tIndices = array();
                    $tArr = array();
                    $tIndices[] = "-1";
                    foreach($keyWordsArr as $keyword)
                    {
                        $t = $db->query("SELECT user_name FROM Table2 WHERE    
  t_text LIKE '%$keyWordsArr[$keyIndex]%'");
                        $tArr[] = $t;
                        while($row2 = $tweet->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {
                            $found = TRUE;
                            foreach($keyWordsArr as $keyword1)
                            {
                                $ret = strpos(strtolower($row2['t_text']),  
     strtolower($keyword1));                                    
                                if(($ret == 0) &&  
     strcmp(strtolower($row2['t_text'][0], strtolower($keyword1)[0])))
                                {
                                    $found = FALSE;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if($found == TRUE)
                            {
                                $ret = strpos($tIndices, $row2['t_id']);
                                if(($ret == 0) && strcmp($tIndices[0], 
     $row2['t_id']))
                                {
                                    $tIndices[] = $row2['t_id'];
                                    $countData[] = $row2['user_name'];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $keyIndex++;
                    }
                ?>

                <tr><td><?php echo $row['keywords'];?></td>
                <td><a href="showt.php?keyword=<?php echo 
    urlencode($keyWord); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo count($countData); ? 
    ></a></td>
                <td><a href="showt.php?keyword=<?php echo 
        urlencode($keyWord); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo 
      count(array_unique($countData)); ?></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
```

And this is the code in page 2 showt.php -

```
      $keywords = $_GET['keyword'];
      $sql="SELECT col1, col2, col3 from t AS s INNER JOIN users AS p ON 
      s.user_name=p.user_name where s.t_text LIKE '%$keywords%'
```

Comment: your mysql query?

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan Added the mysql php code. Please see

Comment: ok try my answer below

Comment: My code is similar to the code in your answer. I think the counts in page 1 tcount.php are shown correctly but the results in page 2 showt.php are not showing correctly. As explained in my post, I am getting results with keyword1 keyword2 and not those results which have another word between keyword1 and keyword2

Comment: your first page giving results fine?

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan Yes, first page is giving fine results. The second page is not giving the required results

Comment: can you flag with mysql error, have to see exact query string

Comment: There is no error. Just that page2 is not fetching those results which has another word between keyword1 and keyword2

Comment: yes. i need to see actual query in page2

Comment: @Gopalkrishnan This is the query of page 2. I have edited it into the main post also 

     $keywords = $_GET['keyword'];
      $sql="SELECT col1, col2, col3 from t AS s INNER JOIN users AS p     
      ON 
      s.user_name=p.user_name where s.t_text LIKE '%$keywords%'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139829/discussion-between-gopalakrishnan-and-user20152015).

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` statement of your query should look like:

```
WHERE my_text_field LIKE ?
```

and the binded parameter should be `%$keyword1%$keyword2%`

In order to define the `$keyword1` and `$keyword2` variables you can do something like:

```
list($keyword1, $keyword2) = explode(' ', $_GET['keyword']);
```

or you can simply use `"%" . implode('%', explode(' ', $_GET['keyword'])) . "%"` in case you have multiple possible keywords

Comment: This is for page1 or page 2 (Please see my edited post)

Answer (score 0):

There is a two way
one is hard way doing by php and mysql

```
$keyword = $_GET('keyword');
$keywordArray = explode(" ",$keyword);
$queryString = "";
foreach($keywordArray as $key=>$value) {
    $queryString .= " column_name LIKE '%$value%' OR";
}
"SElECT * FROM table WHERE ".$queryString
```

second is mysql itself, that is Full text search

Comment: @Gopalkrishnan Please tell how to do Full text search for my purpose